# Covering number of $l_2$ Ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering

What is the covering number $N(\epsilon, B_2, ||\cdot||_2)$  of a ball $B_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of radius $r$ under the $l_2$ norm?

Comment: In what space exactly?

Comment: @NateEldredge The space is $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some dimension $d$. And the ball is the $l_2$ ball.

Comment: Okay.  The focus on $l^2$ and the [tag:banach-spaces] tag made it sound like you had infinite-dimensional spaces in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\epsilon$-covering number of the euclidean unit ball in $\mathbb R^d$ scales like $(1/\epsilon)^d$. More formally,

> **Lemma.** If $\epsilon < 1$, then $(1/\epsilon)^d \le N(\epsilon, B_2) \le (3/\epsilon)^d$. Else $N(\epsilon,B_2) = 1$.

*Proof.* See **Theorem 4.2** and **Example 14.1** of this manuscript http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/lec14.pdf. $\quad\quad\Box$

Now, use this to get (an estimate of) the covering number of $rB_2$, for any $r \ge 0$.