# Upper bound of covering number of $\ell_1$-ball under $\ell_2$-norm

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering

Let $B^n_1 = \{x : \Vert x\Vert_1 ≤ 1\}$ be the $\ell_1$-norm unit ball. How can we prove the covering of $B^n_1$ under $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ satisfies

$$\sqrt{\log N(B^n_1, \Vert\cdot\Vert_2, \epsilon)} \lesssim \min(\epsilon^{-1}\sqrt{\log n}, \sqrt{n}\log(1/\epsilon))$$
where $N(\cdot)$ denotes the covering number.

---

Upper bound of covering number of $\ell_2$-ball under $\ell_2$-norm lies [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356310/covering-number-of-l-2-ball-in-mathbbrd), using [Example 14.1](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Eyw562/teaching/598/lec14.pdf). I try the similar way but could only got a looser bound, namely $$N(B^n_1, \Vert\cdot\Vert_2, \epsilon)\lesssim \sqrt{\pi n}(\frac{3}{\epsilon})^n(e\pi)^{-n/2}$$
It's easy to see that this bound is weaker than the two listed above. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: The first bound follows from the Sudakov inequality. The exact behaviour of covering numbers for the $\ell_1$ ball are computed for example in these lecture notes, see equation (15.4)
http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/lec15.pdf